# How to show all stores in the side panel with the Google Maps Store locator Utility Library

Tags: google-maps, maps, sidebar

I'm using Google maps store locator utility library to display stores and I want to know how can I show all the stores in the sidebar panel rather than a fixed number of stores

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by going into the store-locator.compiled.js file. Do a search for 10 (which is the default) and changing that to 100. That left me room to grow.